# Script that works in Jupiter Notebook does not work as expected in IDE

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've completed a familiar beginner Python project (bank account, running balance - you'll all recognise it instantly)in Jupiter Notebook and it works perfectly. In in Jupiter Notebooks, the balance gets updated when a deposit and/or a withdrawal is made. I want to make an app with a GUI with the code but it doesn't work in my IDE (IDLE).

I've copied the code into IDLE so it look like below:

```
class Account():
    def __init__(self, owner, balance):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

    def __str__(self):
        return("Account holder: {}\nBalance R".format (self.owner, self.balance))

    def deposit(self, dep_amt):
        self.balance = self.balance + dep_amt


    def withdraw(self, with_amt ):
        if self.balance >= with_amt:
            self.balance = self.balance - with_amt
        else:
            print("insufficient funds")

cust1 = Account("Hernandez, Jose", 100.00)


print("\n", cust1)


cust1.deposit(100.00)
# cust1.withdraw(300.00)


print("\nAccount Holder: ", cust1.owner)
print("Account Balance: R", float(cust1.balance))
```

I would have thought that if the script is run consecutive times, "cust1.deposit(100)" would be triggered every time and the balance increase by 100, just like it does when I repeatedly run cust1.deposit(100) in Jupiter Notebook. But this doesn't happen. The balance stays the same at 200 (the initial balance of 100 plus the 100 deposit).

What am I doing wrong?

Andre

Comment: After program exits, all created objects are deleted. If you want to preserve the state of the account during multiple sessions, you must save it outside this code, e.g. to database, or file, to keep it simple. Or, for your learning purposes, just put `cust1.deposit` into loop

Comment: In Jupyter, the kernel is running all the time (unless it crashes or you kill it), so any variable persists. You can even initialise a variable in the bottom cell and then use it in cells further up the page (thus screwing up your workbook the next time you run it in order from opening). It sounds like your IDE runs the program and then shuts down the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter notebook, you would have declared the `class Account` on one cell and would have used `cust1.deposit(100)` on a different cell. In Jupyter notebook you can individually execute a portion of your code which allows you to run `cust1.deposit(100)` multiple times hence the balance is getting increased every time. But in IDEs you can't execute a portion of code multiple times. When you run it, the entire code gets executed which means balance is initialized to 100 and it is increased by 100 once when `cust1.deposit(100)` is called. Hence you see a balance of 200 not matter how many times you run it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as intended. The problem is that when you run your python script directly from IDE it runs only once, but Jupyter Notebook works differently. When you run line of your code in Jupyter, the result of that action is remembered in what I can only describe as "python session". The reason why balance is 300 is because you probably ran cell with `cust1.deposit(100.00)` two times. If you want to do this in script you should execute same command two times:

```py
cust1 = Account("Hernandez, Jose", 100.00)
cust1.deposit(100.00)
cust1.deposit(100.00)
print("\n", cust1)
# will print balance with value of 300.00
```